# Бесконечный редирект nginx при включении config.force_ssl = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Система такая юбунта 14,04 рельсы 3,2,22 руби  1.9.3 гем пасседжер 5.1.4 Когда я в конфиге рельсовв (production.rb) снимаю коммент из строки config.force_ssl = true - тогда идет бесконечный редирект на сайте.

Конфиг nginx:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/passenger-5.1.4;
    passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/wrappers/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

server {
        listen       80;
        root /home/deploy/apps/application/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_min_instances 3;
        passenger_friendly_error_pages off;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        location ~ ^/assets/ {
            root   /home/deploy/apps/application/current/public;
            gzip_static on;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
         }

        location ~ \.(aspx|php|jsp|cgi)$ {
            return 410;
          }
    }
    # HTTPS server
    #
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        root /home/deploy/apps/application/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_min_instances 3;
        passenger_friendly_error_pages off;
        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /home/deployer/apps/ssl/shared/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /home/deployer/apps/ssl/shared/ssl.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location ~ \.(aspx|php|jsp|cgi)$ {
            return 410;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так бывает, когда серверу приложения невдомёк, что ему пришёл HTTPS-запрос, если nginx просто не передаёт никаких признаков этого. Вот [исходник процедуры, распознающей HTTPS](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb#L186-L198). Она, правда, сильно новее ваших рельс, но принцип тот же.

Answer (score 0):

В рельсах не понимаю, но обычно требуется делать rewrite в nginx с 80 на 443:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name site.org www.site.org;
        rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}
```

У меня все сайты так настроены.

Кроме того, иногда помогает включение strict:

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
```

Answer (score 0):

Passenger'ом не пользовался, но помню тоже столкнулся с проблемой цикличного редиректа после включения ssl в Rails конфиге, причем команда rewrite, как в соседнем ответе, не помогала. Вот мой рабочий конфиг(часть) для сервера с puma.

```
upstream {{ app_name }} {
    server                      unix://{{deploy_directory}}/shared/tmp/sockets/puma_{{ app_name }}.sock;
}

server {
    listen                  *:443 ssl spdy;

    server_name             www.{{webserver_name}};  
    root                    {{ deploy_directory }}/current/public;
    resolver                127.0.0.1;
}

### Принудительное использование HTTPS
server {
    listen                  *:80;
    server_name             www.{{webserver_name}};    

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;  # enforce https
}
```